# ArcGIS Server WMS content URL for reverse proxy

Tags: arcgis-server

I configured my ArcGIS Server behind the IIS reverse proxy. My ArcGIS Server machine named as `gisserver` . And I changed my ArcGIS Server manager system property:

```
WebContextURL : https://myservices.domain.com/arcgis
```

So, when I get the ArcGIS WMS capabilities XML document from the internet using reverse proxy, the WMS inner URLs are following:

```
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://gisserver:6080/arcgis/services/Countries/MapServer/WmsServer?"/>
```

How can I change urls as my domain as following?

```
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://myservices.domain.com/arcgis/services/Countries/MapServer/WmsServer?"/>
```

ArcGIS Server version is 10.5.